# adding pagination to a foreach loop in wordpress

Tags: wp-query, categories, pagination

Am looking for a way to implement pagination on my categories I tried to use `paginated_links();` functions but it works only for posts, and not the actual categories. I have looked around and it seems this is a little trickier than I was expecting...

```php
    $cats = get_categories(
        array('parent' => $cat->cat_ID)
      );
                // loop through the categries
                foreach ($cats as $cat) {
       
          echo '<div class="card">';
                    // setup the cateogory ID
                    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
          echo '<div class="card-body">';
          // make images for the category
        
          echo '<div class="card-title"><a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a> <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>';
          echo '</div>';
                    // create a custom wordpress query
                    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=3");

                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <?php echo '<div class="blog-list-points">' ?>
                        <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
            <a href="<?php the_title();?>">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <hr>
          </a>
          <?php echo '</div>'?>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; echo ' </div> '// done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
            
                <?php } 
        // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Comment: I would avoid using the `query_posts` functions, it is not something that should ever be seen in modern WordPress, and there are zero advantages to using it over superior alternatives such as `WP_Query` or `get_posts`. You also have no cleanup function after your loop, Otherwise can you be more specific about how the pagination is expected to works? You won't be able to use any of the paginations functions or APIs WordPress provides, do you mean per-card pagination? Or a single pagination for all cards?

Comment: okay sir thanks for the updates, i want to display 3 categories per page and add pagination to for the rest of the categories

Comment: so you want each category card to have its own pagination? Or do you mean there is a single pagination that moves all categories to the next page? Your comment didn't clear that up, it's still unclear what you wanted. Where does the pagination go and how many paginations are there? E.g. if there are 5 categories, do I see 5 independent pagination interfaces that work on a specific category each? Or 1 pagination interface that is used for all 5 categories? It's very unclear, some information is being assumed and not shared.

Comment: " do you mean there is a single pagination that moves all categories to the next page?" yes sir,
 e.g if i have 20 different categories i want to display only 5 per page and add pagination for the rest of the categories

Comment: ok, in the meantime can you replace the `query_posts` call with a normal query such as a standard `WP_Query` loop, and indent the code correctly? It's very difficult to work with, a standard query should look like this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#usage